# Problem with CSS style sheet functionaltiy

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an HTML page in VS Code and trying to style a div, however none of the settings in my CSS stylesheet seem to be working.

I have confirmed my HTML is referencing the CSS file and ran the CSS code through the W3C CSS validator.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="sytlesheet" type="text/css" href="/Untitled/csss/style.css">
    <title>License Managert</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login">
        <textarea rows="1" cols="20">
        password
        </textarea>
        <button>
        Authenticate
        </button>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: gray;
}

.login{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: In your <link> tag, you have misspelled "stylesheet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<link rel="sytlesheet" type="text/css" href="/Untitled/csss/style.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Untitled/csss/style.css">
```

you have stylesheet misspelled.